# asp.net WebAPI list in Get request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest

I understand in Web API Get request, we can pass the list of inputs in query string like

Products?id=1&id=2&id=3

so the Get action method in ProductsController will be

```
Get([FromURI] int[] id)
{
}
```

My question now is, if the list of inputs to the Get call is much more  (assume 1000), what is the recommended approach?

Comma separated values in query string will be some help. But that won't help in my case.Is there any other way to pass these inputs other than in query string?

Comment: Create a custom class and use JSON: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization

Comment: thanks Garrison for your comments. This works even for Web API Get? Also, is this a limitation in web api that in web api Get request, parameters can be sent only in query string?

Comment: It should allow you to send content from the body of the http request. Its not ideal though to have a body on a get request. It doesn't follow good REST practices. Is there a reason why you want to pass through 1000 ids in your get? It seems to me that there could be a better solution to how you are doing your project. A good solution could be using [Odata](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options)